# Open another content page in Xamarin Form

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to Navigate from MainPage to another ContentPage in Xamarin Forms, but it throws some un-descriptive error message. I am following [Hierarchical Navigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical), but it doesn't help. The error appears in Android and IOS, but I didn't check with UWP as it is not required.

My App.cs

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new  MainPage());
}
```

and in MainPage, I have button click event

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   await Navigation.PushAsync(new Page1());
}
```

and Page1.cs and Page1.XAML

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Skip)]
public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
{
   public Page1 ()
   {
     InitializeComponent();
   }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="LocalDatabaseTutorial.Page1">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

and Also error message [image: Error screen shot]
At first, what is the error message? and How do I navigate from one page to another page in Xamarin forms?

Comment: The code that you have shown looks fine (not sure why you are skipping XamlCompilation on Page1, but other than being a little slower to load/instance, that should not matter). What version of the Xamarin.Forms package are you using, and are they matched versions across all your projects??

Comment: Thank you! O dumb me, I updated Xamarin, but forgot to update all projects. I was using different Xamarin versions. Updating all to the same version solved the problem.

Comment: Please add that as a solution, May be it can help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that *all* your `Xamarin.Forms` have matching versions between your projects (.NetStd libraries containing the Xamarin.Forms package, Xamarin.Android|iOS application projects, etc...).

Typically (always?) a `...resolve type with token XXX from typeref...` exception comes from a mismatch of a compiled/IL type from a runtime type (i.e. same assembly name but different version at runtime).